# Does FPT allow for doubling the parameter?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity, treewidth

I have recently come across a result that showed that a given problem is in FPT when parameterized by the treewidth of a graph. However, they did this by showing that the problem is in FPT when parameterized by the treewidth of an augmented version of the graph that had treewidth of at most 2k+1 when the treewidth of the original graph is k.

Why is it possible do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be the parameter. Is an algorithm has a running time of the form $O(f(2k+1) \cdot \text{poly}(n))$ for a suitable function $f$, then it also has a running time of $O(g(k)  \cdot \text{poly}(n) )$ for $g(k) = f(2k+1)$.